# JPA static metamodel for multiple persistence units

Tags: jpa, static, metamodel

JPA: for the generated static metamodel, for example,

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    private Long id;
}

@StaticMetamodel(...)
public class Foo_ {

    public static volatile SingleAttribute<Foo, Long> id;

}
```

If the entity class Foo is in multiple persistence units(each persistence unit has a Metamodel), each Metamodel has a different `ManagedType` instance for the Foo class.  which metamodel does the static attributes (e.g. id in the example) belong? Each attribute has method `getDeclaringType()` which returns `ManagedType`.

Comment: A static query class is created ONCE for an entity, so an entity class corresponds to a static query class. It can be USED BY any persistence unit that needs it. No idea what you mean beyond that.

Comment: what is the static query class? metamodel class?

Comment: The class with the "_".